# Finishing off my 'make folders from database' class

Tags: java, mysql

The below is a class for making local folders from database entries where each folder has a name, id and parent-id.
I have put it together as best I can but do not know enough to finish it off.

I need to "just grab the folder with id 0 and start building your Files on the disk, using folder.getChildren() as a convenient way to move down the tree then just mkdirs()" as told to me in another post but I do not understand how and where to do it. Please help

```
public class Loop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int PID = 0;
    int RepoID = 1;
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/document_manager";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "Pa55w0rd";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map<Integer,Folder> data = new HashMap<Integer,Folder>(); 
    while( PID < 50 )
    {
    try {            
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("SELECT name, category_id, parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '"+PID+"' AND repository_id = '"+RepoID+"'");
        while (result.next ())
        {

            String FolderName = result.getString ("name");
            String FolderId = result.getString ("category_id");
            String ParentId = result.getString ("parent_id");
            int intFolderId = Integer.parseInt(FolderId);
            int intParentId = Integer.parseInt(ParentId);
            System.out.println( FolderId+" "+FolderName+" "+ParentId );
            //intFolderId = Integer.valueOf(FolderId);
            //intParentId = Integer.valueOf(FolderId);
            Folder newFolder = new Folder(FolderName, intFolderId, intParentId);
            data.put(newFolder.getId(), newFolder);
            }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

     PID++;

}
    for(Folder folder : data.values()) {
        int parentId = folder.getParentFolderId();
        Folder parentFolder = data.get(parentId);
        if(parentFolder != null)
            parentFolder.addChildFolder(folder);
        }
} 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically reading hierachies from the database is not trivial, but if you read one level per query that should be doable.

What you need to do is the following:

- select all folders that have no parent, those are your root folders
- create the folders if they don't exist already
- repeat the following until you don't get any more results from the db
  - select all folders whose parent id is the id of the folders read in the previous iteration (or the parents)
  - assign the read subfolders to their parents based on the parent id
  - create the read subfolders in their parents

This would allow you to use a breadth-first approach, i.e. you read one level of folders per iteration and map the children to the parents using parent_id.

As an alternative you could read the children for a single parent and iterate over the hierarchy in a depth-first manner.

Comment: The thing is, I cant figure out how to select an object (the one with a id of '0', if I could I would be able to just add the children and mkDirs for it and all children..

Comment: @user961574 I'm not sure I understand your problems, but what is wrong with `SELECT ... FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL ...` (or maybe `... WHERE parent_id = 0 ...`)?

Comment: Because that is already done, all results from the database have been made into objects, they are all linked in the correct order, just need to be able to select the object with the id of 0 and tell it to get its children and make directory from top down. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: @user961574 isn't the key for `data` the id? If so, what about `data.get( new Integer(0) )` ? - However, if the code you posted above is your real code, I'd suggest to rework that part in order to improve structure and flexibility (you iterate from PID 0 to 50, what if there are less or more?).

Comment: Thank you for that, I have a class called getMaxId that requests the max category id and i use the result as the max. i just didnt include it on this version so some reason :D

SELECT MAX(category_id) FROM categories WHERE repository_id = '"+UserDetails.repo_id+"'

Then used MAX(category_id) as the limit of loops.